# finding files on android os

Tags: find, android-emulator

There is no utilites like find, grep , "ls -laR" to find files in Android os. IS there a way or is there a list of current default files in the os file system hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a local copy of the files using `adb pull /system system; adb pull /data data` and use your favorite tools to search on your development machine. Or you can install [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) on the emulator, which gives you something intermediate between the extremely limited built-in command line and a full unix command line.

Comment: Busybox seems better: Ihave managed to do it:

Find File system list

<pre>
Get http://android-dls.com/files/apps/busybox.xxx

PS adb push busybox.xxx /data/local/

# /data/local/busybox.xxx find / > /mnt/sdcard/fileslist

PS adb pull /mnt/sdcard/fileslist android22-fileslist
919 KB/s (1038142 bytes in 1.102s)
</pre>